# What is the real meaning of せずに in Japaneses language?

Tags: meaning, culture

I don't know anything about Japanese language; I'm just researching about Japan.

I got an email that said *(This is summery)*:

**There is no meaning (concept) for sin in Japanese culture, and the shame is the only  deterrence concept *(means in some other countries people do not do bad things because it is sin!), and Japanese people are not familiar with the concept of sin! ... Shame is an earthy concept and sin is a divine concept.***

Then I used Google to translate sin to Japanese, Google returns せずに, I found out there is translation for sin in Japanese language, but I don't know about Japanese culture....

Is the above bold statement true? Describe please

Comment: While there's some problems with this question (like the doubling over related to "sin" as the Latinate preposition without), I'm not quite sure why it's meriting heavy downvoting. Could someone explain? I think the question about how the concept of sin vs. 罪 works is an interesting language-based and answerable question.

Comment: It boils down to "I don't know Japanese, but I put a word into Google Translate. Is Google Translate correct?  I've made no other effort to answer my own question."  I think these usually get closed as off topic.

Comment: @virmaior: I second your opinion.

Comment: "I used Google to translate sin to Japanese, Google returns せずに" --> Really? https://translate.google.com/#en/ja/Sin

Comment: Hey you had it translated "Spanish to Japanese"! https://translate.google.com/#es/ja/Sin

Comment: Have you probably had a look at this page? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_views_on_sin

Comment: "the shame is the only deterrence concept" >> Heh.. but my parents, grandparents and (nursery school?) teachers used to tell us, 嘘をつくと閻魔様に舌を抜かれるぞ！(If you tell a lie, Enma Daio will rip out your tongue!) 悪いことをすると、地獄に落ちるよ (If you do bad things, you will go to hell (after you die)!) そんなことをすると[罰]{ばち}が当たるぞ！(If you do such a thing, Heaven will punish you!)"

Comment: I'm very glad Google knows better than translating "sin" into "正弦"...

Comment: @Choko: As I wrote in my answer, "sin" in the monotheistic religions means *failure to fulfill his/her contract with God*. The e-mail wonders why the Japanese, without the concept of "sin," still maintain certain ethical level, and attributes it to the concept of "shame." The ethical creeds you cited are not in the form of commandments comprising a contract between you and god(s). So they are not considered to stipulate "sin" in the monotheistic sense. For a typical example of commandments (stipulating sins), you may want to look at this -> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Commandments .

Comment: If we Japanese don't have the concept of "sin in the monotheistic religions, which means failure to fulfill his/her contract with God", does it mean "There is no meaning (concept) for sin in Japanese culture", "the shame is the only deterrence concept", and "Japanese people are not familiar with the concept of ANY KIND OF sin"?

Comment: @Choko: That "the shame is the only deterrence concept" is what the e-mail is asserting and not my opinion. And that the Japanese are not familiar with the concept of sin does *not* mean the Japanese are unethical. On the contrary, the e-mail shows his/her surprise that the Japanese maintain certain ethical level, as I wrote before. Remember "sin" is a concept characteristic to monotheistic religions. Other religions have their own sets of ethical canons that are not of contract-commandment form.

Comment: So, is this about the difference between religious people's concepts and non-religious people's concepts or other kinds of religious people's concepts? Then I don't see why and how OP and the email author specify the target which is whole Japanese culture here. Anyway, I agree with snailboatさん. I am sorry for answering a off topic question.

Comment: @choco Thank you very much. your comments helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there are many kinds of words meaning sin([罪]{つみ}) in Japanese language.

Japanese Wikipedia has a list of links to details about each kind of 罪.
https://goo.gl/ceJhFg

More than 127 million Japanese people live in Japan now. Every Japanese person has human rights and freedom. What Japanese people believe are diverse. So, the reason someone does not do bad things is a personal matter with her/his religious freedom or other kind of freedom. I think that thinking of this matter as culture is not productive if you really want to know facts.

By the way, do we(human) have only two choices, sin or shame, in deterrence concepts actually? **Where is love? Where are other important things to live?** How can only Japanese people lack them except shame, with a fact that each Japanese person has a human body, human brain and human heart just like people in other countries?

Anyway, both you and your friend have human rights and freedom to believe anything. I respect that. But my answer here is **"No, the bold statement is not true. It's not even a fair way to analyze people in other culture."**

Answer (score 2):

"せずに" means "without doing."  This is another instance that Google translator gives funny results.

That said:

Japanese Christian texts generally translate "sin" into "罪{つみ}". This is not very appropriate since "罪" primarily means "crime."

I guess the e-mail wants to convey something like...

As the majority of the Japanese are non-monotheistic, there is no concept of "sin" in their culture. Then how do they discipline themselves? The answer is the concept of "shame."

If you are interested in that viewpoint, I recommend you read "The Chrysanthemum and the Sword" by Ruth Benedict.

***   added   ***

I don't know if this helps, but...

"Sin" in the monotheistic religions roughly means "failure to fulfill his/her contract with God." I don't believe the majorities of the Japanese think this to be equivalent to "罪".

Comment: Thanks. I didn't get, You mean, the email is right? there is no concept of sin in Japanese culture? and Japanese people are not familiar the concept of sin?

Comment: @Kermani: You are welcome. And if you men "an immoral act considered to be a transgression against divine law" by "sin", the answer is "Yes."

Comment: If you know other countries culture, Is shame and sin meaning closely to gather (For Japanese)?

Comment: I think so. For the Japanese, "shame" is the feeling you have when you do something "undignified, disgraceful." (As for the cultural matter, I know Christianity well and have a modest glimpse of Judaism and Islam. Do you think I am eligible to talk about this issue?)

Comment: (I voted up, but another user voted down, unfortunately) Of course you are, you know other countries and religions and other views. Thanks a lot.  But please edit your answer, and answer more clearly, and describe more please. I want to send the link of your answer to the sender of that emai

Comment: @virmajor: Thanks for rectifying my roundabout expressions.

Comment: @Kumari: Thanks. Can you be more specific in which way my answer can be enhanced? Please indicate. I will try then.